# How to create a child modal window in Electron.NET?

Tags: c#, parent-child, electron.net

I am creating an app using `Electron.NET.` Although in Electron there is the possibility to create a window passing its parent in the window options, i cannot seem to be able to do that in `Electron.NET.`
I tried also to use the `BrowserWindow.SetParentWindow` method but it is not working, it throws a js exception that `getWindowById.setParentWindow` function does not exists.

Comment: See description of Electron Net at following site : https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET.  Is the child and parent window running on same machine?  Same operating System?  Same user account?  Do you have app running as "Admin"?

Comment: I am building an app using Electron.NET, I think it implies that i have already read the description.. Yes in all other questions, although i do not understand how 2 windows of the same desktop app would run on another machine etc.. :)

Comment: You need to process ids on remote machine.  You would have to return the parent process id from first windows connection on second machine; and then pass to second window.

Comment: Sorry but i do not understand what you are suggesting.. Could you please explain with more details? I have read the documentation etc, but it is my first Electron.NET app..

Comment: I'm not an expert on Electron.Net.  Probably best if you ask the Electron Net experts.  It looks like it is possible by using : routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");  where id would be the process id on the remote machine.

Comment: Ok, Just to explain myself better, I am able to create a second window, just not as a child to another one but as a separate window